# Indicators (dots) with CSS scroll snap

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a scrolling carousel using CSS scroll snap.

```css
.carousel {
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  width: 100vw;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.carousel > * {
  display: inline-block;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

#x {
  background-color: pink;
}
#y {
  background-color: lightcyan;
}
#z {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel">
<div id="x">x</div>
<div id="y">y</div>
<div id="z">z</div>
</div>
```

It works pretty well; if you scroll the carousel with the trackpad or with a finger, it snaps to each item.

What I'd like to add to this are "indicators." e.g. in Bootstrap, these are little dots or lines indicating that there are multiple things in the carousel, one indicator per item in the carousel, with the current item highlighted. Clicking on an indicator will typically scroll you to the specified item.

[image: bootstrap screenshot with carousel indicators]

Do I need JavaScript for this? (I assume so.) How should I detect which item is currently visible?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The way to handle this in modern browsers is with [`IntersectionObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API). In the below example, the `IntersectionObserver` fires its callback whenever one of the child elements crosses the 50% threshold, making it the element with the largest `intersectionRatio`. When this happens, we re-render the indicator based on the index of the currently selected item.

Bonus tip: You can use `scroll-behavior: smooth` to animate the `scrollIntoView` call.

```js
var carousel = document.querySelector('.carousel');
var indicator = document.querySelector('#indicator');
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel > *');
var currentIndex = 0;

function renderIndicator() {
  // this is just an example indicator; you can probably do better
  indicator.innerHTML = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var button = document.createElement('button');
    button.innerHTML = (i === currentIndex ? '\u2022' : '\u25e6');
    (function(i) {
      button.onclick = function() {
        elements[i].scrollIntoView();
      }
    })(i);
    indicator.appendChild(button);
  }
}

var observer = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries, observer) {
  // find the entry with the largest intersection ratio
  var activated = entries.reduce(function (max, entry) {
    return (entry.intersectionRatio > max.intersectionRatio) ? entry : max;
  });
  if (activated.intersectionRatio > 0) {
    currentIndex = elementIndices[activated.target.getAttribute("id")];
    renderIndicator();
  }
}, {
  root:carousel, threshold:0.5
});
var elementIndices = {};
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elementIndices[elements[i].getAttribute("id")] = i;
  observer.observe(elements[i]);
}
```

```css
.carousel {
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  width: 100vw;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  scroll-behavior: smooth
}

.carousel > * {
  display: inline-block;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 80vh;
}

#x {
  background-color: pink;
}
#y {
  background-color: lightcyan;
}
#z {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel">
<div id="x">x</div>
<div id="y">y</div>
<div id="z">z</div>
</div>
<div id="indicator">• ◦ ◦</div>
```

Comment: Can you please edit your Javascript code for not creating buttons with dots, but creating one div element, and one inner span element inside of that div, whitch will be moving from left to right base on position and what you observing for carousel?

Comment: What you're describing is a scroll bar. Just use a scroll bar! https://css-tricks.com/the-current-state-of-styling-scrollbars/

Comment: It seems to me that the correct solution is this:
`active.intersectionRatio> 0.5`

Since when scrolling to the right, the 2nd slide is called first, and then the 1st. Because of this, the point rises to the wrong place (on the 1st). The line above solves this problem, because one slide decreases the ratio (e.g. 0.48) and the other slide increases (e.g. 0.52).

Comment: No, it works well like this for me:
`threshold: 1` and `active.intersectionRatio >= 1`

Comment: I'm a bit late to this post, but the accepted answer is working perfectly for me (much appreciated)

Is there was to used custom SVG's instead of the unicode dots?