# How to create clickable carousel dots for CSS snap points carousel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm working on trying to get my CSS Snap Point carousel working with navigation dots generated by a bit of jQuery.

My aim is for the user to be able to click the dots to slide the carousel across or to simply wipe the carousel cards and the dots automatically update, to show the user which slide they're on.

Here is my code:

```js
               (function($) {
                    $.fn.has_scrollbar = function() {
                          var divnode = this.get(0);
                          if(divnode.scrollHeight > divnode.clientHeight) {
                              return true;
                          }
                          if(divnode.scrollWidth > divnode.clientWidth) {
                              return true;
                          }
                   }
                })(jQuery);

                $(window).on('load resize', function() {
                    if($('.team-players').has_scrollbar()) { 
                       $('.team-players').addClass('overflow-detected');   
                    } else {
                       $('.team-players').removeClass('overflow-detected');   
                    }
                });


var elements = $('.team-players .team-member');
var dotsContainer = $('.css-snap-dots');


$(elements).each(function(i){
     var count = i;
     var dot =  document.createElement('span');
     dot.innerHTML = "&bull;"
     dot.setAttribute("data-id", count);
     dotsContainer.append(dot);
});

$('.css-snap-dots span:first-of-type').addClass('active');
```

```css
.team-players {
    justify-content: center;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
}
.team-players .team-member {
    width: 285px;
    /*min-width: 285px;*/
    min-width: 260px;
    background: white;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 30px 0 0;
    scroll-snap-align: center;
    /*padding:0 10px;*/
}

.team-players .carousel-stage {
     display: flex;
}
.team-players .team-member:last-of-type {
    margin-right: 0;
}

.team-players .team-member img {
    width: 100%;
}
.team-players .team-member span {
    display: block;
}
.team-players.overflow-detected {
    justify-content: left;
}

.css-snap-dots {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40px;
}
.css-snap-dots span {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 10px 0;
}
.css-snap-dots span.active {
    color: lime;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="background: #f5f5f5; padding: 70px 30px; max-width: 320px">
    <div class="who-we-are-today team-players">
    <div class="carousel-stage">
        <div class="team-member">
            <img src="/on/demandware.static/-/Library-Sites-FigleavesSharedLibrary/default/images/aboutus/Tori@2x.jpg" alt="Tori">
            <div class="member-details">
                <span class="member-name">Tori Shelton</span>
                <span class="member-job">Garment Technologist</span>
                <div class="member-quote">“Lipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.”</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="team-member">
            <img src="/on/demandware.static/-/Library-Sites-FigleavesSharedLibrary/default/images/aboutus/Daniella@2x.jpg" alt="Daniella">
            <div class="member-details">
                <span class="member-name">Daniella Stern</span>
                <span class="member-job">Buyers Admin Assistant</span>
                <div class="member-quote">“Lipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.”</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="team-member">
            <img src="/on/demandware.static/-/Library-Sites-FigleavesSharedLibrary/default/images/aboutus/Lucy@2x.jpg" alt="Lucy">
            <div class="member-details">
                <span class="member-name">Lucy Caw</span>
                <span class="member-job">Junior Buyer</span>
                <div class="member-quote">“Lipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.”</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="css-snap-dots">
          
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is set a global variable and  value to it like if want it to scroll like 300 to right when you click dot1 do globalVar = -300px and add this wih template literal to you slider wrapper like transfrom :`translatex(${globalVar}px)` and on dot 2 globalVar = -600px set globalVar Initially to 0;

https://github.com/naveenkash/ride-share/blob/master/src/components/how-it-work-slider.vue

Comment: and for dagging use my gist https://gist.github.com/naveenkash/4e219ed62969da442c5d349c7c7399f2

Comment: I found this solution that's works perfectly, see: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53355384/indicators-dots-with-css-scroll-snap

Thanks for your help