# Add class to one div when another is in the viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a website using vertical scroll snap. The website is divided into full width and height sections and I would like to style the navigation and other elements depending on which of these sections in in the viewport.

I have tried a lot of answers I have found online without success. The closest I can get it to work is this:

```
var targets = document.querySelectorAll('section')
var obsOptions = {
  root: null, // measure against the viewport
  threshold: .5 // how much of the element should be visible before handler is triggered
}

let handler = (entries, opts) => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (entry.intersectionRatio > opts.thresholds[0]) {
      document.body.classList.remove(...document.body.classList);
      document.body.classList.add(entry.target.id + '-active');
    }
  })
}

targets.forEach(el => {
  var observer = new IntersectionObserver(handler, obsOptions);
  observer.observe(el);
})
```

This works well except it removes all the classes off the body and the WordPress theme adds its own which are necessary for it to function so I can't have that

If I remove the line about removing the classes - ALL the section ID's show as classes at the same time.

I thought the best way would be to not apply it to the body, but to a container that had no other classes - so I have wrapped everything in a container div with a class of

```
.full-page-container
```

I tried editing the code to this

```
var targets = document.querySelectorAll('section')
var obsOptions = {
  root: null, // measure against the viewport
  threshold: .5 // how much of the element should be visible before handler is triggered
}

let handler = (entries, opts) => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (entry.intersectionRatio > opts.thresholds[0]) {
      document.full-page-container.classList.remove(...document.ful-page-container.classList);
      document.full-page-container.classList.add(entry.target.id + '-active');
    }
  })
}

targets.forEach(el => {
  var observer = new IntersectionObserver(handler, obsOptions);
  observer.observe(el);
})
```

but it doesn't work.

How does one apply this same effect to a div rather than the body

Any help would be much appreciated

Here is a codepen I have put together

https://codepen.io/shereewalker/pen/bGaqqmy

Comment: What is "vertical scroll snap"? Some element that stays fixed as you scroll down the page?

Comment: Apologies, it is when the content displays as vertical slides like this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53355384/indicators-dots-with-css-scroll-snap?fbclid=IwAR1ZaYU-KTCbUa936G52OgLRUqHqByuU_Oul3nb6C9IPb-3gsMqih0MlA_0

But vertically rather than horizontally

Comment: The html structure is the same, is just scrolls in sections and snaps between them so a user never sees to panels at once - except of course for when it is scrolling

Comment: when you do `document.body.classList.remove(...document.body.classList);`, you're saying remove ALL classes from the body, you're basically sending in a list of ALL classes on the body, and asking to have them all removed. Why not just specify which class you're wanting to remove. like this `document.body.classList.remove("full-page-container")`
make sure you don't have a `.` before the class name

Comment: Because the classes I want to remove would be different each time. For example, if I have three sections #red #green #blue, this applies .red, .green and .blue to the body. When red in in the viewport I need it to remove the others and so on - I have several sections

Comment: A codepen or similar might be useful to demonstrate your use case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the remove you are spending the content of classList and I think therefore are removing all the classes.

I would suggest filtering the classList for classes that contain `-active` (The class you add) and then removing those.

```
var targets = document.querySelectorAll('section')
var obsOptions = {
  root: null, // measure against the viewport
  threshold: .5 // how much of the element should be visible before handler is triggered
}

let handler = (entries, opts) => {
  entries.forEach((entry) => {
    if (entry.intersectionRatio > opts.thresholds[0]) {
      const classesToRemove = findClassesWithActive(document.body.classList);
      if (classesToRemove.length > 0) {
        document.body.classList.remove(classesToRemove);
      }
      document.body.classList.add(entry.target.id + "-active");
    }
  });
};

targets.forEach(el => {
  var observer = new IntersectionObserver(handler, obsOptions);
  observer.observe(el);
})
```

```
    function findClassesWithActive(classList) {
       return classList.filter(c => c.includes('-active')
    }
```

[Codepenne with it working](https://codepen.io/IamSimonSmale/pen/qBprPLL)

Comment: Hi there - thank you for your input, I'm sorry but I don't know to incorporate that into the original code. Could you help?

And yes - it removes all the classes. Thanks

Comment: I have edited the answer to include your original code with my new function.

Comment: Thank you - this doesn't seem to work, it may be to do with my other JS

I will out the URL above but I can try and out together a codepen

Comment: I would break it out to a codepen with the minimal functionality. You might just have a typo that will be apparent when it is in a smaller piece

Comment: Okay so I have included a codepen

https://codepen.io/shereewalker/pen/bGaqqmy

Comment: @MrToad I have added a code pen to my answer with it working. you'll see as you scroll that there is a white border on the `h1` that disappears on the Red one as the classes change

Comment: Yes! This is great. I'm not sure what was changed but it's now working perfectly. Thank you so much!